# C++ Project dependencies issue Visual studio 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++-2005

I am working on a dataManagement project that periodically deletes files in a specific folder. The solution has three projects of which, one is the application and the other two are static libraries. Now I want to add one more project which is a static library used for logging. The logging static library project has a header file which the application project refers. When I build the solution, I am getting error as the header file is not found. When I added the logging static library project, I also made the application project dependent on it by checking the appropriate bix in the project dependencies.
Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs an additional include file path to reference the header file directory...

Project->Properties->Config Properties->C/C++->Additional Include Directories

it doesn't auto pick up the header file paths, it just knows how to link to the project.... Its completely undefined where the header file should be.  or even if you have a header file, you can forward reference the thing in the other project if you like!

Comment: +1 ... and I would just add ... don't forget to set change the additional include directories for ALL configurations. The number of times I forget this....!

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to do to get a statically linked library working in VS. The compiler needs to be able to find the declaration for the symbols that you're referencing and the linker needs to be able to resolve the full definition. When you add the .lib file to the VS project this meets the second obligation. To meet the first you must include the header somewhere in your source hierarchy before the first reference and you must also tell the project where to find the header files. The dependency settings in VS only set the build order - they will not help here. You need to make sure that the folder that your header files are in is added to the "Additional Include Directories" setting in the project properties, or is one of the global include directories in the main VS Options. You must also make sure that the .lib is added to the linker's "Additional Dependencies" setting.